# Changing video quality based on device using MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, apportable

I used an MPMoviePlayer to play an .mp4 video within my app, which works fine. I tried my app on an Android device using Apportable but the video wasn't playing till I later realized that it was because the video quality was too high for the device. Is it possible to change the video quality (of an .mp4) based on the device running the app using MPMoviePlayer? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: you need a high and low quality version of the movie in your bundle, then decide to play one or the other depending on what device it is

Comment: I was trying to keep the bundle size as small as possible

Comment: Well, in that case just don't play the movie on devices that can't play that movie. There's no other choice here, include both files or lower the overall video quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply have one video that plays on iOS and one that plays on Android via Apportable, you could opt to simply have two files of the same name where one file is added to the project and attached to the iOS build target and the other is attached to the Apportable build target.